# Ajax script doesn't insert into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make friends system and friend adding with ajax. The problem is that when I click on the button nothing happen. Doesn't insert anything into database. So this is the button

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="newFriend has-tooltip pull-right" data-title="Add as friend" id="'.$id.'"" ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Add as friends </a>
```

and this is the `add_friend.php`

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect(); 

if(!empty($_POST["id"])) {

    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];   

            $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE friend_id= ? and id = ?'); // BDD query, page ID values
            $value->bindParam(1, $friend_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $value->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);              
            $value->execute();
            $result = $value->fetch();    

if( $result > 0) {
        echo 'already added';           
}
else 
{
    $friend_id = $_POST['id'];             
    $id = $_SESSION['id']; 

    $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO user_friends (friend_id, id)
                            VALUES (:friend_id, :id)");   
    $query -> execute(array(
                      ":friend_id"         => $friend_id,
                      ":id"          => $id
    ));     
}
```

and this

```
<script>    

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.newFriend', $('.buttons')).click(function(){
    $.post('misc/add_friend.php', 
    { 
        "id": $(this).attr('id'),
    },
    function(data){
        if(data == 0){
            $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added as friend!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }
        else {
             $('#message_newfriend').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">User is already in your friend list!</div>');
             $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
             }); 
        }
     });
});
});
</script>
```

Table is simple `user_friends` - whit rows - `friend_id (int 4)` and `id (int 4)`

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: did your ajax loading?

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console to see if any errors are thrown? (For Chrome you can press F12)

Comment: If you talk about console - I don't see anything into console of web browser.

Comment: look at the `Network` tab on chrome

Comment: why you have this `$('.newFriend', $('.buttons'))`, is `.button` is ancestor of `.newfriend`?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali yes this was the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
$('.newFriend', $('.buttons')).click(function(){
               ^            ^// wrong method
```

change it to,

```
$('.newFriend, .buttons').click(function(){
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Now is working. Thank you!

Comment: I will once countdown for accepting is over i.e. in 7 minutes.

Comment: Just to mention that with your solution got error because there is one `)` more.. When I removed it I got it to work - `$('.newFriend, .buttons').click(function()`

Answer (score 1):

First select a browser for testing your ajax call. Either Google Chrome or Firefox with Firebug plugin are good. My preferred choice is Firefox.
Here is how i debug with Firebug in Firefox press F12:
firebug opens then click on Net tab, then click on XHR,there you will see the data passed between your browser and the server.
You must identify if the problem is on you clientside script or on the server side script.
Every time you make a request, there is a new url displayed under XHR, click on the plus sign at the beginning of the url string, there you can see Header,Post,Response, JSON, Cache and cookie tab, these are the stuffs passed back and forth between the browser and the server.

The Post tab shows the datas sent by your browser, the Response  tab shows datas sent by the server afterwards.
If there is an error server side, generated by your php script, you'll see it there.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. It will help me for future problems!

Comment: You're welcome, and for the client side script problem if any, you can see it in the Console tab at the same level than the Net tab.

Comment: I know for the Console tab and there was nothing this time but didn't know how to use Net tab :)